# Remove all elements but one from page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove all elements but one from a webpage.

First I find my element using `getElementById()`. I then move it to the top of the body via `document.body.appendChild()`.

How can I then remove the rest of the nodes, but this one node I have?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the element, saving a reference. Remove everything else. Then insert the saved element.

```
var node = document.getElementById("whatever");
if (node.parentNode) {
    var savedNode = node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}

while (document.body.firstChild) {
  document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
}

document.body.appendChild(savedNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can first select your html node like this:

```
var selectedNode=document.getElementById("myid");
//remove it from DOM
selectedNode.parentNode.removeChild(selectedNode);
//clear the body
document.body.innerHTML = "";
//append the selectedNode
document.body.appendChild(selectedNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're removing all the nodes in the documents body, I would suggest copying the node you want, removing all nodes from the document, and then appending the node you copied. For example:

```
test = document.body.getElementById(bla);
document.body.empty();
document.body.appendChild(test);
```

Comment: So, where does this `empty()` function come from? I hope you're not confusing it with jQuery's [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)... because you've used it improperly and this question isn't tagged with [tag:jquery].

Comment: `empty()` doesn't exist in JavaScript. (It is a jQuery method, though.)

Comment: It's a jQuery function used on HTML elements. You can read about it [Here](http://w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_remove.asp)

Although it's not JavaScript, it serves its purpose

Comment: @Jake `document.body.empty()` isn't even how you'd invoke that function. It would go more like `$("body").empty()`. So, your code is wrong _and_ you've provided a jQuery answer for a javascript question.

Comment: @canon Thank you, i totally forgot. Haven't used it in a while.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but maybe someone needs an answer. You can write `document.body.innerHTML = ''` or create this function instead. Here's the code: `document.body.empty = () => document.body.innerHTML = ''`

Answer (score 0):

```
var remain=document.getElementById('id'),
pa=document.body;

remain=remain.parentNode.removeChild(remain);// remove and save referenced element

while(pa.lastChild) pa.removeChild(pa.lastChild); // remove all other nodes

pa.appendChild(remain); //add element to empty body
```